# Can I delete the Matlab installation file in root user home directory

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I just found Matlab (2016a) put a 2.5 Gb installation files that it fetched during the installation in the root home directory (Linux mint 18), under `/root/Downloads/MathWorks`. I guess it is probably because I use `sudo` for installation.

My question is:

1. Is it normal that program store information when user executes it with `sudo`?
2. Can I delete the file under `/root/Downloads`? (My limited Linux knowledge told me do not touch anything in the `/root` folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When you execute anything with `su...do`, you basically execute it 'as' `root`.
- Mathworks uses the Download-Folder (which is in your case `/root/Downloads` - since you have executed the installer as root) for temporary data (According to https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/229835-is-the-mathworks-folder-necessary-to-run-properly?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).
- So, yes. It seems like you can delete the folder.
- Or just move it to `MathWorks.bak` and check if Mathworks still works properly. In case everything is working fine, you can delete `MathWorks.bak`.

Answer (score 3):

1. A program can do anything when run as `sudo` and depends only on what the program is designed to do. `sudo` simply elevates the permissions when running a given command.
2. I would have thought that the installer would have downloaded everything to `/tmp` instead of `/root/Downloads`, but as long as you didn't select `/root/Downloads` as your installation directory for MATLAB and this is only the temporary download location you can certainly remove it after successfully installing MATLAB to a "typical" location such as `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a`.

Comment: Thanks! Is `/user/local/` a better place to install program than `/home/[username]/`?

Comment: @GTWu If you want other people besides `[username]` to be able to run it, yes. It should be the default location when running MATLAB's installer.